# Push notifications with back stack (Pending Intents, Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, webview, wkwebview, onesignal

I'm facing a problem with passing the launch URL from one activity to another, without creating a new Intent for my MainActivity.

I have a webview, which is work with OneSignal push notifications. I wanted to modify the grouping notifications content.

If there's a way to get the result I want (modifying notifications group layout for OneSignal) That would be awesome. I'll simply use the One Signal default action and that would be the best solution for me.

If I have to implement it on that way:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group

The problem is, when I start a new child activity of the MainActivity, I don't use the "StartActivity / StartActivityForResults" functions.
This is the extension of OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler (OneSignal class)
It's outside of my MainActivity class.

```
    class NotificationServiceExtension : OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun remoteNotificationReceived(
        context: Context,
        notificationReceivedEvent: OSNotificationReceivedEvent
    ) {
        val notification = notificationReceivedEvent.notification
        val bigText = Html.fromHtml(notification.body, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
        var smallText = Html.fromHtml(notification.additionalData["cleantitle"] as String, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
        val summaryStatistics = Html.fromHtml(notification.additionalData["setSummaryText"] as String, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()

        if (smallText == "test") {
            smallText = Html.fromHtml(notification.additionalData["smalltitle"] as String, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
        }
        else{
            val name = Html.fromHtml(notification.additionalData["text"] as String, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
            smallText += " from $name"
        }

        val smallContent = RemoteViews("com.webviewapp.mywebviewapp", R.layout.small_layout_notification)
        val sum = RemoteViews("com.webviewapp.mywebviewapp", R.layout.summary_layout_notification)
        val bigContent = RemoteViews("com.webviewapp.mywebviewapp", R.layout.large_notification_layout)

        bigContent.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, smallText)
        bigContent.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content, bigText)
        smallContent.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, smallText)
        sum.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, summaryStatistics)
        notificationReceivedEvent.complete(null)


        var bp: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            bp =Picasso.get().load(notification.largeIcon).get()
            smallContent.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.noti_pic, bp)
            bigContent.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.noti_pic, bp)

        }
        catch(e:Exception){
            print(e)
        }

        try {
            val fid = notification.additionalData["fid"] as String
            notificationId = fid.toInt()

        }
        catch(e:java.lang.Exception){
            notificationId += Date().time.toInt()
        }

        val notificationOpenActivity = Intent(context.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra("launchURL", notification.additionalData["pushURL"] as String)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)


        val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(context.applicationContext).run {
            // Add the intent, which inflates the back stack
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(notificationOpenActivity)

            // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
            getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }


        val receivedNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context.applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myIcon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.applicationContext,R.color.blue_primary))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()) // to expand button
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(500, 500, 500))
            .setCustomBigContentView(bigContent)
            .setCustomContentView(smallContent)
            .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(sum)
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .build()


        val summary = NotificationCompat.Builder(context.applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myIcon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.applicationContext,R.color.blue_primary))
            //.setContentTitle(summaryStatistics.toString())
            .setContentTitle(summaryStatistics)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                .setBigContentTitle(summaryStatistics)
                .addLine(summaryStatistics)
                .setSummaryText(summaryStatistics))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build()

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context.applicationContext).apply {
            notify(notificationId, receivedNotification)
            notify(SUMMARY_ID, summary)
        }


    }
}
```

And the notifications work good as I want. The problem is, How do I pass from the child activity the extra parameter to it's parent if I didn't create that child from the parent? I simply want to load it's URL into my webview, but also keep the back stack.
Also, how can I make sure I don't create multiple MainActivity if I won't use that child?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Notification Back Stack

Android's documentation page ["Start an Activity from a Notification"](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#kotlin) covers the back stack use case under the "Regular activity" suggestion.

> #### Regular activity
>
> This is an activity that exists as a part of your app's normal UX flow. So when the user arrives in the activity from the notification, the new task should include a complete back stack, allowing them to press Back and navigate up the app hierarchy.

I see you are using the `addNextIntentWithParentStack` method on `TaskStackBuilder` already in your code so looks like you may have already followed that page.
However there is one thing wrong with Google's docs here, the `requestCode` sent to `getPendingIntent` should be a unique value for your app.
Example:

```
   getPendingIntent(
      1234, // NOTE: Change this to a unique requestCode for your app
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
   )
```

*I have [filed an docs issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228349794) with Google on this.*

Lastly, since I didn't see this in your question make sure you have correctly added `android:parentActivityName` to your Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` per Android's ["Define your app's Activity hierarchy"](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#define_your_apps_activity_hierarchy)

#### OneSignal Details

##### Notification Tracking

Note that calling `notificationReceivedEvent.complete(null)` means OneSignal won't know anything about your notification you're displaying with `NotificationManagerCompat`. This changes a few things:

- Click counts won't be sent to OneSignal
- Notification won't be restored. (notifications are automatically cleaned when the app is "force stopped", device is rebooted, or app is updated)

##### Notification Groups

OneSignal can already do the grouping and summary you have in your code. Just set the ["Group Key"](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications#androidhuawei-options) on the dashboard, or [`android_group`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#grouping--collapsing) if you are sending the notification with the REST API.

#### Back stack

OneSignal doesn't allow you to control the back stack, it simply just always resumes that app and leaves the back stack un-effected. However you can disable this default behavior with [`com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/android-customizations#changing-the-open-action-of-a-notification) and use your own `startActivity` from the `OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler`.